# 3g direct between two android devices

Tags: networking

Is it posible to connect two or more android devices using 3g bypassing the provider infrastructure. Or in other words is it posible for a android mobile phone to recieve the sending signal directly from a other phone and take action on that. Can I add a private Sim card to realise this connection between a set of phones using a duals SIM phone.
Phone B is recieving the send signals from Phone A using a second SIM card adjusted for the good frequencies. By exchaning the role of master and slave we can transmit and recieve signals in the G3 band. To be legal we need a subscrition for A and |B
Is it posible in Android to realize this senario. Swiching between two connections in the same phone?

Phone  1

slave  SIM A_______send
master SIM B____   | 
                |  |
                |  |
                |  |
Phone 2         |  |
slave SIM  A____|  |
Master SIM B_______|recieve

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this, on Android or any other kind of mobile phone. It's just not how the 3G network works. Each operator's 3G network runs on a frequency band allocated to them by the government. The cell transmitter runs on its own hardware that your phone doesn't have, with a high-power radio transceiver that needs more power than your phone has.